# Vector Map Iteration forward / reverse

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qt4, dictionary

I have an ordered set of key/value maps in a vector I'm iterating through.  I know a unique key, and based on that, I need to get the key/value pairs before and after it until I hit a limit.  For instance:

```
QVector < QMap < QString, QString > > map;
QMap < QString, QString > temp;

temp.insert("key1", "parent");
map.append(temp);
temp.clear();
temp.insert("key2", "value1");
map.append(temp);
temp.clear();
temp.insert("key3", "value2");
map.append(temp);
temp.clear();
temp.insert("key4", "value3");
map.append(temp);
temp.clear();
temp.insert("key5", "parent");
map.append(temp);
```

Let's say I have a value "key3", and I want to get the key/value pairs before "key3" until "parent" is reached, and after it until "parent" is reached (not including "parent"), how do I do this?  I can't think of an easy way.

```
QMap < QString, QString > newMap;

QMap < QString, QString >::iterator i;
for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); ++i) {

     QMap < QString, QString > vectorMap = map.at(i);
     for (j = vectorMap.begin(); j != vectorMap.end(); ++j) {

          if (j.key() == "key3") {

               //set a bool to true and
               //get j.key() and j.value() before and after until "parent" is reached
               newMap.insert(j.key(), j.value());

          }
     }
}
```

The newMap would have key/value pairs ("key2/value1", "key3/value2", "key4/value3");

Edited for what I'm trying now:

```
QString selection = "key3";

 //for going backwards, still need to go forward
 for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); ++i) {

    QMap < QString, QString > vectorMap = map.at(i);
    QMapIterator < QString, QString > iter(vectorMap);

    while (iter.hasNext()) {

        iter.next();

        if (iter.key() == selection &&  iter.value() != "parent") {

            do {

                previousText = iter.previous();

                tempMap.insert(iter.key(), iter.value());
                newMap.append(tempMap);
                tempMap.clear();

                qDebug() << "previousText" << previousText;
                iter.previous();

            } while (previousText != "parent");

        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: "I want to get the key/value paris before 'key3' until 'parent' is reached, and after it until 'parent' is reached', how do I do this?"

Comment: Okay, I think I have a better idea of what you're really trying to do. Given some key, you want to get each `QMap` stored in your `QVector< QMap >`, and insert everything between "parent" values in that `QMap`, if that segment of the map contains your key.

Comment: Yes!  I can't figure out a decent way of doing it.  My Edited code above throws an error, and I'm still not sure it's the simplest solution.

Comment: @user375566, I've updated my code to do what you want, but it's highly untested since I don't work in C++/Qt any more. Commented it so you know what I'm at least trying to get at.

Comment: Does each of the QMaps in the QVector always contains only 1 key-value pair? If so, why not just use QMap directly?

Answer (score 0):

**edit** Now that I think I understand the problem, here is a solution off the top of my head.

Note that this takes advantage of a few characteristics of `QMap`, namely that when you iterate through a `QMap`, it iterates through in key-order. It does not deal with the situation where your `QMap` has multiple equal keys.

Highly untested, and pretty hack-ish at the moment, but it should get you past your current hurdle, I hope.

I tried to make it clean enough for you to understand the logic, but you could use `QMap::iterator` alone to move back and forth to determine what range to copy.

```
QVector < QMap < QString, QString > > map;
QMap < QString, QString > temp;

// populate your maps...

QMap < QString, QString > newMap;

// traverse your QVector< QMap<QString, QString> > map...

QString selection = "key3";

QVectorIterator<QMap<QString, QString> > vecIter(map);
while (vecIter.hasNext()) 
{
     // pull out your QMap<QString, QString>    
     QMap<QString, QString> tempMap = vecIter.next();

     // see if selection exists in the map
     if (tempMap.find(selection) != tempMap.end())
     {
         // find list of keys that map to "parent"
         QList<QString> parentKeys = tempMap.keys("parent");

         // get the Key that maps to "parent" that precedes 'selection'
         QString preKey;

         QListIterator<QString> liter(parentKeys);
         while (liter.hasNext())
         {
             if(liter.peekNext() < selection)
             {
                 preKey = liter.next();
             }
             else
             {
                 // we've passed the selection key, break the loop
                 break;
             }
         }

         // now traverse the map and copy
         // QMap::upperBound returns an iterator to the next greatest key after the key you give it
         QMap<QString, QString>::const_iterator mit = tempMap.upperBound(preKey);
         for(; mit != tempMap.constEnd(); ++mit)
         {
             if ((*mit)->value() != "parent"))
             {
                 newMap.insert((*mit)->key(), (*mit)->value());
             }
             else
             {
                 // break out because we've just encountered the "parent" value after our selection
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
} // while (vecIter.hasNext())
```

Comment: No, the map should include "key3", and I can't get that to work.  I edited my code to show what I'm trying, and I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: use your map's "find" function (or whatever) to get an iterator that points to the item you're looking for ("key3"). Construct a reverse iterator from that "key3" iterator. In two separate loops advance each of those two iterators until what it points at contains "parent". Within each loop collect the elements as you go.